# how to show only the arrays that contain object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to filter some elements from my array. So if the element key is found in array show only those arrays that include that.

```
{"result":["b", "f", "h"], "model":3, "path":3, "resultnumber":56, "otherproducts":["e"]},
{"result":["b", "f", "j"], "model":3, "path":3, "resultnumber":58, "otherproducts":["e"]},  
{"result":["b", "g", "h"], "model":11, "path":3, "resultnumber":59, "otherproducts":[]}
```

So in this case if my key is "h" it should show only first and third array.

My code looks like this now but I am stuck trying to find a way to display only those.

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.Data.results.length; i++){
     var checkObject = s.Data.results[i].path == 3;
     console.log(checkObject);
     if (checkObject){
        if(option in s.Data.results[i].result){
            console.log(s.Data.results[i].result);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: can you please give a more detailed explanation of your variables! which id your object!?

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran so in my case `option` is the element from array that I select in this case is `h` so if `option` is in result which is equal with  `["b", "g", "h"]` show the result otherwise hide it

Comment: var filtered = data.filter( o => o.result.includes("h")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use filter, to exclude the objects that don't match your parameters

```js
var data = [{"result":["b", "f", "h"], "model":3, "path":3, "resultnumber":56, "otherproducts":["e"]},
{"result":["b", "f", "j"], "model":3, "path":3, "resultnumber":58, "otherproducts":["e"]},
{"result":["b", "g", "h"], "model":11, "path":3, "resultnumber":59, "otherproducts":[]}]

var filtered = data.filter( ({ result }) => result.indexOf("h") > -1)

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at [how the `in`-operator works in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
It doesn't check if the given array contains this property, it checks whether the array has the index `option`.

I guess what you are looking for is something like `s.Data.results[i].result.indexOf(option) !== -1)` (Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/4119086), for more details on variants of `contains()` equivalents)